# shell wildcards

Tags: shell, grep

i tried to google this but can't find a satisfactory answer. it's probably very straightforward so apologies if it's basic stuff

what is the difference bewteen

```
grep "first" */*html
```

and

```
 grep "first" ./*html
```

i know that dot(.) in the second line stands for 'current directory'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
grep "first" */*html
```

expands as all html files in all subdirectories (one-level only) from the current dir.

```
grep "first" ./*html
```

expands as all html files in the current dir. the './' is what limits it the the current dir.

**EDIT**

Per @lisko 's comment

Hidden files and directories mean files beginning with the '.' character. If you want to search ***ALL*** files, use

```
grep "first" ./*html ./.*html */*html */.*html
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

The first line will grep through all files that match filenames ending with "html" one directory below the current directory because the first "*" will match any directory.

The second line will grep though all the files that match filenames ending with "html" in the current directory.

Note that hidden files or hidden directories won't be matched.